# How to reduce embedded duplicated font in pdf

Tags: vb.net, itext

I had writed a code that should work but I have a problem because when i open file maked by this procedure Adobe say me that's wrong.

This procedure should make a file that has not a duplicated font.

```
Using msDoc As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            Using document As iTextSharp.text.Document = New iTextSharp.text.Document()
                Using copy As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy(document, msDoc)
                document.Open()

                Dim pdfReader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader("C:\Users\pier\Desktop\prova.pdf")
                For i As Integer = 1 To pdfReader.NumberOfPages
                    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i))
                Next

                msDoc.Position = 0
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Users\pier\Desktop\file213.pdf", msDoc.ToArray())
            End Using


        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

### You grab the bytes before the result document is finished.

The result PDF is finished after `document` has been closed. In your case `document` is closed implicitly in the `End Using` and you retrieve the stream bytes before that. Furthermore, you play around with the stream position (`msDoc.Position = 0`) before `document` is closed, so you additionally cause the end section of the PDF to overwrite its start...

Furthermore, don't put the `PdfSmartCopy` instance into a `Using` line; this instance is implicitly closed when `document` is closed but you attempt to close it before.

Thus, do instead:

```
Using msDoc As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Using document As iTextSharp.text.Document = New iTextSharp.text.Document()
        Dim copy As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy(document, msDoc)
        document.Open()

        Dim pdfReader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader("C:\Users\pier\Desktop\prova.pdf")
        For i As Integer = 1 To pdfReader.NumberOfPages
            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i))
        Next
    End Using

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Users\pier\Desktop\file213.pdf", msDoc.ToArray())
End Using
```

### Removing duplicate fonts

You say

> This procedure should make a file that has not a duplicated font.

Your code removes very specific duplicate font entries. Whether it removes all from your document, depends on whether they all are of that specific type.

Comment: Code now work but duplicated font aren't deleted. Do you have a solution to my question?

Comment: Please share the pdf in question for analysis. Probably the "duplicate fonts" are not duplicate at all but *different subsets* of the same font.

Comment: I can't share original pdf because it have sensible data that i can't share. Click on this link to see font properties https://i.ibb.co/sg7DHMC/Immagine.png

Comment: If *"Sottoinsieme incorporato"* means something like *embedded subset*, then most likely the "duplicate fonts" are ***not* duplicate** at all but ***different* subsets** of the same font.

Comment: Yes sottoinsieme incorportato means embedded subset but each font is equal to another one.
You can think about this operation.
You have 10 pdf where the content is "Hello World, VariableName" where variableName is a name that is different in 10 pdf. Each pdf has times new roman embedded font.
if you merge all pdf you obtain 1 pdf with 10font embedded that are a copy of times new roman (this is what happens in my code) so I search a optimizer to make a file that is composed by only one font

Comment: I'm sorry, without the document this is pure guesswork. (Even with the document, though, I most likely cannot help because iText does not provide the feature of merging different subsets of the same font.)